# In R, is there a way to color plot points on a gradient based on a range of numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R, and I've been able to plot points, but wondering if there is a way to apply a color gradient to the scatterplot.

I have a 3 column matrix, where the first two will be used as coordinates, and the third has range of numbers between 0 and .0001. Is there a way to color the plot points based on where they fall in the range of numbers?

```
 x   y   z
 15  3   6e-4
 34  22  1e-10
 24  1   5e-2
 ...

plot(x, y, main= "Title", ylab = "column y", xlab = "column x", col = rgb(0,100,0,50,maxColorValue=255), pch=16)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm big on the `ggplot2` package, because it does a lot to encourage good plotting habits (although the syntax is a bit confusing at first):

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, z=z) #ggplot2 only likes to deal with data frames
ggplot2(df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=z) + #create the 'base layer' of the plot
  geom_point() + #represent the data with points
  scale_colour_gradient(low="black", high="green") + #you have lots of options for color mapping
  scale_x_continuous("column x") + #you can use scale_... to modify the scale in lots of other ways
  scale_y_continuous("column y") +
  ggtitle("Title")
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
plot(x, y, col = gray(z/0.0001))
```

This is by gray.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but for benefit of others this may be what you were after:

```
mat = cbind(sample(1:30), sample(1:30), 10*rnorm(30,mean=5))
n = 255
data_seq = seq(min(mat[,3]), max(mat[,3]), length=n)
col_pal = colorRampPalette(c('darkblue','orange'))(n+1)
cols = col_pal[ cut(mat[,3], data_seq, include.lowest=T) ]
plot(mat[, 1:2], col = cols, pch=16, cex=2)
```